# Festvox Voices. Where can I find them

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am building a new app and I want to use Festvox voices. Anyone know where I can find them?

http://www.tomsoft.co.uk/iphone/flite.htm

Comment: check it, http://festlang.berlios.de/docu/doku.php?id=languages Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Bing is your friend : http://festvox.org/

Comment: There aren't any voices there that I can use to compile.